# How to return TIFF image from remote api using multiple header parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

I'm creating a spring application to access a remote API that returns a TIFF image. the api is expecting a few parameters send in the header.  I'm attempting with the following code from examples I've found.. but when I return the ResponseEntity respond, it's of 0 length and the byte[] respond is null.

{Content-Length=[0], Content-Type=[application/octet-stream], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.5], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], Date=[Wed, 19 Aug 2015 15:14:17 GMT]}

```
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new    ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter()); 
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(messageConverters);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

    headers.set("Accept", "application/octet-stream");

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("http://webservices.imagestorehouse.com/GetData.svc/getDocs")
            .queryParam("token", "a80d4978c12549dbafcd1922c1efdaa5")
            .queryParam("company_id", "SW1112b")
            .queryParam("document", "1" )
            .queryParam("field_1", "2627594")
            .queryParam("field_4", "028000");

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    //ResponseEntity<byte[]> respond = restTemplate.execute(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class);
    byte[] respond = restTemplate.getForObject(builder.build().encode().toUri(), byte[].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add few more parameters in response header.

```
header.setContentLength(respond.length);
//Also set content type accordingly
//header.setContentType(new MediaType("application", "xml"));
```

Comment: debug your respond byte[] for length in controller.